# Encountering "unknown filesystem type 'hfsplus'" when mounting external drive?

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount, arch-linux

I'm running ArchLinux and when trying to mount a partition from an external HDD I encounter:

```
mount error: unknown filesystem type 'hfsplus'
```

Upon formatting the partition I encountered the same error with btrfs.
I'm using UDisks2 and tried to install different tool like hfsprogs without success.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, rebooting as [advised here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=141560) fixed the issue.